# AS400 IBM Toolbox for Java doesn't have classes to read Journal in the latest version of Jar JTOpen 400

Tags: jar, db2-400, toolbox, journal, jt400

JTOpen - The IBM Toolbox for Java: In the JT400 jar version 20.0.0 JTOpenlite (com.ibm.jtopenlite.command.program.journal) package  is deprecated which has the classes to read the Journal classes like
RetrieveJournalEntries
RetrieveJournalReceiverInformation
which are used to read the journals.

Please let me know the exact package or jar file which can be used to access the Journals in IBMi DB2 system.

I looked the maven m2 repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jt400/jt400) and the github documentation (https://github.com/IBM/JTOpen) and I couldn't find the classes (RetrieveJournalEntries
RetrieveJournalReceiverInformation) in all the versions of the jar files.

Answer (score 1):

Likely depreciated in favor of SQL and the [DISPLAY_JOURNAL function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-display-journal-table-function)

```
SELECT journal_code, journal_entry_type, object, object_type, X.* 
FROM TABLE (
  QSYS2.Display_Journal(
            'PRODDATA', 'QSQJRN', -- Journal library and name
            OBJECT_LIBRARY=>'PRODDATA', OBJECT_NAME=>'SALES',
            OBJECT_OBJTYPE=>'*FILE', OBJECT_MEMBER=>'SALES' 
    ) ) AS X
WHERE journal_entry_type in ('DL', 'PT', 'PX', 'UP') AND "CURRENT_USER" = 'SUPERUSER'
ORDER BY entry_timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

JTOpenLite has been removed from 20.0.0 as documented at the project's [home page](https://github.com/IBM/JTOpen).

> Immediate removal of several antiquated components of JTOpen,
> including
>
> ```
> JTOpenLite
> jt400Android
> jt400Micro
> jt400Proxy If you need these packages, please acquire older versions from the archive site on [sourceforge][2] (breaking change)
> ```